# Is possible to delete all debugger directives while pushing to git repo?

Tags: javascript, git, push

It´s possible to run some kind of script that deletes/drop´s all debugger directives in javascript code while pushing to git repo?

Comment: Sound like a job for: [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: Or a fancy [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Comment: @0stone0... thanks for the reply, but as far as my understanding of .gitignore goes it´s limited to setting what files you want to exclude from pushing. What I´m looking for is something like the TersePlugin for webpack that in the building process of bundling the source code, is able to line by line detect if there is the `debugger` directive and exclude it. Got it?

Comment: @0stone0... yes, perpahs a git hook could do the job... let me see if I can find anything there... thanks for the tip...

Comment: It sounds like there is much more going on. Maybe you could elaborate your question some more? Describe original problem you're facing.

Comment: @0stone0... it´s quite straightforward... I have a git repo, and before pushing a new commit to it, I just want to find a way of dropping all debugger directives of my javascript code, before sending to the git repo. In the building process it´s possible to achieve this using a webpack plugin like uglify or terse plugin as svyatis.lviv mentioned. But I need the same functionality while pushing to the project git repository.

Comment: @0stone0... continuing... Your suggestion of using a git hook, I guess it´s the best aproximation for the moment, but as I don´t have too much expertise in python or C, the languages used for the git hooks I´m still having some pushbacks... having to dig and trying to find some usefull use cases of git hooks in the web

Answer (score 1):

You can :

- write a pre-push hook that refuses to push if debugger directives are present in the code you push,
- write another script, which you can call manually, which removes these directives from your code - you can add and commit after that

---

A pre-push hook is not a good place to create or rewrite commits (it would have weird interactions with other actions triggered around a `git push`), it's better to write "ok/ko" actions in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [uglify-js](https://www.uglifyjs.net/) plugin to strip all the unnecessary functions with pure_funcs: [] configuration

Comment: Hy there @svyatis.lviv. This is not for the bundling process in webpack, it´s for the pushing process to the git repo

Answer (score 0):

"While pushing"?

No.

Push exists to push existing history, the history you have. It has nothing to do with creating new history.

You can construct any history you want from the history you have, anything from a custom fast-export⇒filter⇒fast-import to filter-branch or filter-repo can apply arbitrary transforms to existing history, including applying a per-file filter to strip out debugging statements. See the docs for git filter-branch and git fast-import/fast-export and git filter-repo. Then you can push the resulting new history.

Comment: I didn´t was able to follow your reasoning... probably because I´m neophyte to git ecosystem mechanisms. Could you try to rephrase in more simple, perhaps, more verbose way?! Thanks.

Comment: Might have buried the lede a bit there, sorry. Clearer now?